# Nvida NVS 4200M and unsuccesful reboot

Tags: nvidia, dell, reboot, 17.10

I can't reboot my laptop Dell Latitude E6520 properly while running Ubuntu 17.10, I get stuck with a black screen and a blinking cursor. Unfortunately the laptop has a Nvidia Quadro NVS 4200M quadro graphic card along with the integrated Intel HD 3000. During installation I accepted to install third party drivers/codecs.. but I don't know if the Nvidia propietary got installed or rellay got any advantage over the open source ones (Noveau?). I wonder if that option doesn't give enough freedom during installation.. what about if I'm interested in the codecs (mp3 and others) but not in the propietary drivers, perhaps a more fine grain control should help (I guess). I'm new to Ubuntu. Thanks for support :)

EDIT: even opening a vitual console gives me a blinking cursor.. so annoying!

Comment: Unfortunately some companies, as NVIDIA, although having linux-developing actions, don't have a heavy focus on Linux by merely commercial reasons. So we must face this kind of annoyance.

Comment: You need `nomodeset` to boot, then install Nvidia drivers (open Additional Drivers with internet connection, select and apply).